# Getting None in message.guild.get_member_named("member_name")

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm getting NoneType in 
`message.guild.get_member_named("Testing Account")`
and there is a person/account named Testing Account in the discord server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure your bot has `members` intent enabled in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Enable intents in the code, and pass them in your bot/client with the `intents` kwarg.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

> "If your bot tracks presence data, you may need the presence intent to receive presence event data." - Discord Developer Portal

You can find more about intents or privileged intents at [Privileged Intents - Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents) &
[A Primer to Gateway Intents - Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#a-primer-to-gateway-intents)

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've been searching hours for this and this was the problem all along!

(where exactly does the documentation mention this requirement?)

Comment: @Marius I've included some links in the answer

Answer (score 1):

If `.get_member_named()` is returning `None` there could be many reasons causing that. You can **check if...**

- you typed the name of the account correctly
- the account is in the guild in which the message was sent
- the bot has permissions to view the user's profile
- your bot has logged in correctly

If none of those are the case you can have a look at the `get_member_named()` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member_named#discord.Guild.get_member_named) or use [IDs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user) instead of a name (IDs usually work much more reliably).