# How do I print out all the members of a discord server with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

Ok so I want to get all the members of a discord server and when I run the code below it just gives me the name of my bot. There's no error or anything so I'm wondering if there's anything I can do.

```
@client.command()
async def testcommand(ctx):
  
    members = ctx.message.guild.members
    
    for member in members:
        print(member.name)
```

I've tried to run this in an on_message but it gives the same result. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: Code works fine in my test env so It's likely due to not having presence data intents enabled. See my answer here for a bit more info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65356391/13151806

Comment: Oh, thank you it was enabling intents.members that worked. Is this anywhere in the docs?