# Trying to check for a role in a member's acquired roles list

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to have the code check for a role in a member's role list. But this simple task turned out to be harder than I thought. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
    return
  else:
    if message.content == "":
      return
    else:
      role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Bullied')
      member = message.guild.get_member(message.author.id)
      if role in member.roles:
        await message.channel.send(f'Hey there {message.author.name}')
      else:
        return
```

And I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Comment: Do you have intents enabled? I tested the code and It seemed to work fine. See my answer here if you need help enabling intents. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65356391/13151806

Answer (score 0):

Why are you getting `id` from `member` object and then getting the same `member` object from this `id`. Just do this:

```py
member = message.author
```

Also, you have some unnecessary nesting in your code. This:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot or message.content == "":
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Bullied")
    member = message.author
    if role in member.roles:
        await message.channel.send(f"Hey there {member.name}")
    return
```

looks much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take you're changes but this wasn't really what I was looking for. The problem I had has already been fixed :)